# struct within struct in c

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I want to access a struct within a struct, does anyone know how?

**EDIT:**

```
typedef struct{
    int a, b;
} struct_1;

typedef struct{
    int c;
    struct_1 exemple;
} struct_2;
struct_2 Table[100];
```

Here for example I want to assign a value to Table[0].exemple.a

Thank you.
**EDIT:** wow im such a dumba.. sometimes it was working  iits just that my print was printing 100 times whereas I had just 6 entries so I just had to look up on the print thanks anyway

Comment: `Table[0].exemple.a = value;` anything missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Exactly like your example:

```
Table[0].exemple.a = 12;
```

I think your problem is that `exemple` is `struct_2` in your example, and not `struct_1` like it appears you intended.  Try this on for size (with corrected spelling):

```
typedef struct{
  int a, b;
} struct_1;

typedef struct{
  int c;
  struct_1 example;
} struct_2;
struct_1 Table[100];
```

Answer (score 0):

With nested structs you continue to access the properties until you reach what you are looking for like so:

```
Table[0].example.a = 5;
Table[0].example.b = 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably meant:

```
typedef struct{
    int c;
    struct_1 exemple; /* see how it's struct_1 */
} struct_2;
```

and not

```
typedef struct{
    int c;
    struct_2 exemple;
} struct_2;
```

Since `struct_2` doesn't have an `a` field.

After this, `Table[0].exemple.a = 5`, should work, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Your declaration of `struct_2` looks wrong. Replace `struct_2 exemple;` with `struct_1 exemple;`. To access data inside the structure, use the `.` operator or the `->` operator if you are using pointers.